# stopping embedded videos from playing once hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, embedding, vimeo

I have a slider that contains three frames. Each frame represents a play button for an embedded video behind it. When the user clicks the image, it is hidden and the embedded video is shown and starts autoplaying in the same location.

When the user clicks to the next slide, the video is supposed to stop playing and the play frame for the next video should come up.

I can get the first video to stop when the user clicks the next arrow, but then the second video starts playing behind the play frame, even though the video is hidden.

I've tried a bunch of different methods, but nothing can stop that hidden video from playing. I'm using vimeo and I have the api turned on.

```
      $(".holdFrame").show();$(".hiddenVideo").hide();

      $('.holdFrame').click(function(){
        $(".hiddenVideo").show();
        $(".holdFrame").hide();
});
```

That sets it up initially.
And this runs when the next arrow is clicked.

```
var setVideos = (function() {
    $(".hiddenVideo").hide('fast', function(){
        $(".holdFrame").show('fast', function(){
            pauseVideos();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: could I clone() the .hiddenVideo, remove it, and then add it back when the user clicks .holdFrame?